# How do I create a custom administration sub-theme without the tools block name collision?

Tags: theming

A subtheme was created using the drupal console in order to customise the mediteran administration theme.

```
vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal generate:theme --base-theme mediteran
```

When I try to install the theme I get

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: 'block' entity with ID 'mediteran_interlated_tools' already exists. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPreSave() (line 490 of 
core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object) (Line: 263)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->save(Object) (Line: 395)
```

The tools menu is then lost. How do I create a subtheme with the tools menu?

Comment: Did you try [following the documentation on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/creating-sub-themes) instead of using Drupal Console?

Comment: Not having the regions redefined in a subtheme is a trap of using the console. I don't see anything about the creation of blocks. Reviewing the block mapping yes.

Comment: So I've copied everything in config/install. Renamed all the theme references and block id. Deleted the config settings - drush config-list | grep mediteran_interlated and drush config-delete my_setting. Installed without error.

Comment: Drupal Console is dead. Try Drush instead. `drush generate theme`.